# yaml: invalid leading UTF-8 octet

Tags: ubuntu, yaml, containers

I faced with this error("yaml: invalid leading UTF-8 octet") when executing this code on Ubuntu,I checked all the community, but none of the solutions were worked.[image]

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  database:
   image: postgres:13
   volumes:
     - dbwebservice:/var/lib/postgres
   restart: always
   environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: webservice  
    POSTGRES_USER: drupal
    POSTGRES_DB: webservice
    networks:
      - webservice
  
  web:
   image: drupal:latest
   ports:
    - "8083:80"
   restart: always
   depends_on:
    - database
   environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB: postgres:13
      POSTGRES_USER: drupal
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: drupal
   networks:
    - webservice

networks:
  webservice:
    driver: bridge
    name: webservicenetwork

volumes:
dbwebservice:
```

Comment: What do you see in the console? can you add it to the question?

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: When I run your yml on my ubuntu machine, I don't see it

Comment: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`